# Why isn't autodiscover working after updating DNS

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

I just migrated from Office365 to Amazon WorkMail. After updating DNS, I can log in to the WorkMail web application and send/receive emails.

I have the following CNAME record added to DNS:

```
autodiscover    autodiscover.mail.us-east-1.awsapps.com
```

When I try to add the WorkMail account as an exchange account on IOS, I cannot do so without manually entering the server address. It attempts to redirect to login.microsoftonline.com.

Why is this happening?

Comment: How long have you waited? What is the TTL for you MX and autodiscover records? Sometimes you will have to wait that long for changes to propagate.

Comment: @JohnHanley they are both set to 1 hour, and I updated them about 6 hours ago. When I run nslookup I can see the updated records

Comment: What region did you setup WorkMail? Follow this article with a focus on setting up AutoDiscover phase 2. This article also includes debugging tests. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/autodiscover.html

Comment: Are you sure you're updating the right DNS? Have you tried using tools such as http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools to verify DNS changes?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the `autodiscover` record as a `SRV` record, rather than a `CNAME`.